# Card.io in NativeScript - thinkdigital-nativescript-cardio

Tags: ios, paypal, nativescript, card.io

I"m trying to use the Paypal's Card.io with NativeScript.
Card.io is a library that allow you to scan CreditCard using your phone so you don't need to enter the digits manually.

I'm found this plugin : https://www.npmjs.com/package/thinkdigital-nativescript-cardio but there is no documentation on how to use it. I checked the [code](https://gist.github.com/maatthc/82ee1038980149f8ae84f9ec5f151731) (it only supports iOS but it is okay to start with) but I couldn't figure out how to call the scan method properly:

```
CardIO.scanCard().then(
        ()=> console.log("Done!"),
        ()=> console.log("Error!")
    );
```

Have someone used this plugin before? Based on the source code, any idea on how to invoke it correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a NativeScript plugin that wrappers the iOS Stripe pod library.
That supports CardIO under the hood when adding a new credit card. You can find the source code for the plugin here: 
https://github.com/maatthc/nativescript-stripe-paymentcontext